# Can't delete a file

Tags: java

A have such a problem: there are some RandomAccessFiles which are opened through the algorithm. The function they are used in is recursive. SO I can't close them (if I do, I will crash the algorithm). Are there any way to close them (to delete afterwards)?

Answer (score 3):

Start with a non-recursive routine that opens the file, passes it to your recursive routine then closes it when the recursive routine exits.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`File.deleteOnExit()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()), then the files will be automatically deleted when the JVM ends.

Comment: Will not work if he needs to clean up but continue running (such as in a server or a longer running user application).

Comment: Yes, I agree. That is only deleting

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to address this depending on the details of your problem:

- If you have only 1 file, use @Bill K's solution of opening the file in the non-recursive routine before entering the recursive part is a good approach.
- If you have a small number of files to be opened, create yourself a "file manager" class with one method that will open a new file on demand and a second method that will close and delete all open files.  Change the algorithm to open files using the file manager, and put a call to the "close all" method in a the finally clause of a try / finally surrounding the recursive algorithm.
- If you have an arbitrarily large number of files to be opened, you will have to redesign your algorithm so that can open an close them on demand in a sensible fashion.  Or change the algorithm so that it doesn't need to use so many files.

@Michael Borgwardt' solution (don't close the file at all, and mark it as delete-on-exit) is potentially fragile, particularly if the algorithm needs to open a large number of these files.  Many OS platforms have per process limits on the number of open file handles.

Answer (score 1):

Every recursive function must have some kind of abort condition. Just delete the file at the "end" of your recursion.

Btw. you should close every file you open, if your function structure doesn't allow you to do so, you should change it.

Answer (score 1):

With out seeing the algorithm is hard to tell, but even if your using a recursive implementation, you should be able to close it upon the recursive return.

Other approach is to open and close the file outside the recursive function:

For instance:

```
 main() {
    File file = openFile()
    recursiveFunction( file ); // do whatever is needed and pass the file as arg
    file.close()
  }
```

Or open and close the file in your recursive function

```
 void recursiveFunction() {
    File file = openFile()
    doX
    doY
    if( finished() ) { // guard condition executed when returning from the recursion
        closeFile()
    } else {
        recursiveFunction()
    } 
 }
```